# Donations in iOS app using PayPal iOS framework

Tags: ios, paypal, appstore-approval, donations

I know there are other questions regarding this, but the answers are not clear.

Is it possible to use the PayPal iOS framework to implement charity donations inside an iOS app?

If yes, could you give me an example of an app on the Store with this functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#unacceptable)

> 3.2.2 Unacceptable
>
> (iv) Unless you are an [approved nonprofit](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-nonprofits/) or otherwise permitted under Section 3.2.1 (vi) above, collecting funds within the app for charities and fundraisers. Apps that seek to raise money for such causes must be free on the App Store and **may only collect funds outside of the app, such as via Safari or SMS**.